# Creating halo outside the borders of an element in css

Tags: css

I am wondering how to do this in css :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asJsq.png)

Basically, I can do everything out of it. But I dont manage to recreate the halo surroundering the borders. Could you please advise ? :)

EDIT :

I am quite stuck at making the border with the fading

Comment: Did u mean the orange shadow?

Comment: Yes the orange shadow. But also the different color of the border. You can see the border fading in a certain from dark to light and to light to dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This effect can be achieved with box-shadows like so:

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
}

.halo {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 11px rgba(255,165,28,0.59);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 11px rgba(255,165,28,0.59);
}
```

```html
<div class="box halo">Hello There, I am a box, play with my colours to get different results, use the last two pixel values to play with the size and blur.</div>
```

In order to learn more about box shadows in CSS, you can find its documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp